# How to make a sample html input text area that immediately outputs the results on the same page?

Tags: php, html, text, area

How do I make a sample html input text area that immediately outputs the results in another html box on the same page, like they do on this MDN page? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Fundamentals . See the 'Active Learning' section at the bottom of the page. There may be tutorials out there, but hard to find since I don't know what this is called...

Comment: you have to use HTML DOM Events. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

Comment: There's a number of ways to do this but essentially it boils down to using Javascript to fetch the content of the input, maybe pass it through something to format it if necessary, and display it in another element. You'd probably need to bind it to an appropriate event too so it's redone on that event.

Comment: Define immediately. Does it need to update as you type or can it update after submitting the form?

Comment: Update as I type in the html would be better. That's the way it works on MDN. Using a submit button would works as well, but I'd prefer the former.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 1):

You can add a listener to the textarea's `input` event, and copy its `value` to the `innerHTML` of some output element:

```js
var txt = document.querySelector('textarea'),
    out = document.querySelector('div');
    
txt.addEventListener('input', updateOutput);

function updateOutput() {
    out.innerHTML = txt.value;    
}

updateOutput(); // also fill output at page load
```

```css
div { border: 1px solid; white-space: pre-wrap; }
textarea { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<textarea>type some text <b>here</b></textarea>
<h3>output</h3>
<div></div>
```

Comment: OK, good. God this to work, so thanks! (Now I have to create a second text area for the CSS. If I have trouble with that, maybe you could help. I'll let you know!)